# PHP regular expression for validating first and lastname

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use regex to validate the users first and last name on a form.

### Rules

- Must be alphabetic
- First letter can either by uppercase or lowercase
- Followed by all lowercase letters
- Must be at least 2 letters long and cannot be longer than 15 letters.
- No spaces.

This is my attempt at the regular expression

```
!preg_match('/^[a-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,14}$/'
```

But I am getting the error:

> : preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character
>   class at offset 4

Comment: `[a-Z]` -> `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: `[a-Z]` is an empty range because `Z` is before `a` in the ASCII chart. Actually, this is what the error message tries to tell you.

Comment: Do you mean `[a-z]` not `[a-Z]`? Or even [a-zA-Z]? You might want to also consider people called Princess Consuela Bananahammock.

Comment: `{1}` is a no-op. You can remove it and the meaning of the `regex` doesn't change.

Comment: ^([A-z][A-Za-z]*\s*[A-Za-z]*)$

Comment: @TehseenAhmed the `regex` you suggest doesn't follow any of the rules listed in the question.

Comment: @axiac for first and last name

Comment: @TehseenAhmed btw, `[A-z]` includes six non-letter characters: `[`, `\ `, `]`, `^`, `_` and `\``.

Comment: i know but the rule was was not broken

Comment: @Zestyy99 It is true, `[a-Z]` matches any character that lies **after** `a` and **before** `Z` (including these two characters). The trouble is that `Z` comes before `a` in the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and consequently, `[a-Z]` is an empty range (and invalid, as the error message reports).

Comment: Read about [regular expressions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) and use https://regex101.com to validate your expressions (and learn how they match).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a-Z isn't a valid range, you need to change this to include both uppercase and lowercase ranges.

change to this: `^[a-zA-Z][a-z]{1,14}$`

Comment: `{1}` is a no-op. You can remove it from the `regex` and its meaning doesn't change.

Comment: sure, missed that out. cheers

Comment: Thank you for the help, will accept when it lets me :)